# Сколько предложений в тексте?

Tags: синтаксис

Вопрос, возможно, примитивный, но тем не менее возникли сомнения. Сколько предложений в тексте ниже?

> Он сказал: "Пошли домой. Поздно уже".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Сколько предложений в тексте ниже?
>
> ```
> Он сказал: "Пошли домой. Поздно уже."
> ```

Одно, осложнённое прямой речью. Ну а как его разбирать?

См. [у Литневской](http://www.gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm):

> При осложненности предложения прямой речью или вставным предложением
>   они рассматриваются и описываются как самостоятельное предложение,
>   поскольку и прямая речь, и вставное предложение имеет собственную цель
>   высказывания и интонацию, которая может не совпадать с целью
>   высказывания и интонацией самого предложения. Так, например,
>   предложение ***Он с возмущением спросил: «Долго вы еще будете
>   копаться?!»*** следует разбирать следующим образом: предложение
>   повествовательное, невосклицательное, простое, двусоставное,
>   распространенное, полное, осложнено прямой речью. Прямая речь
>   представляет собой предложение вопросительное, восклицательное,
>   двусоставное, распространенное, полное, неосложненное.

**P.S.**

В рассматриваемом нами случае прямая речь состоит из двух предложений.

Answer (score 1):

Хотя всё объяснение у slava1947, конечно, правильно, предложений в вопросе три: одно сложное, содержащее прямую речь, и два в самой прямой речи. Итого три. Это как задачи про треугольники с треугольниками внутри.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, здесь можно найти четыре предложения. Все вместе — предложение. В его составе — три предложения: слова автора плюс два предложения прямой речи. Итого 4 предложения.